# Imagick: unable to assign or convert color profile

Tags: imagick, color-profile

I am having such a hard time trying out to convert images from Adobe RGB to sRGB profile that now I start to think maybe I can't assign or convert color profiles at all on my host.

ImageMagick 6.8.9-6 Q16 x86_64 2014-08-15
class_exists("Imagick") = true

Here I try to assign the profile to an image created with IM, even that does not work..
What is wrong here?

```
try {

    $image = new Imagick();
    $image->newImage(100, 100, new ImagickPixel('red'));
    $image->setImageFormat('jpg');
    $image->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
    $image->setImageCompressionQuality(60);

    // TRY 1
    // $image->setImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);

    // TRY 2
    $profile_path = "sRGB_IEC61966-2-1_black_scaled.icc";
    $profile = file_get_contents($profile_path);
    $image->profileImage("icc", $profile);
    $image->setImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);

} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception caught: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
} 

header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
echo $image->getImageBlob();
```

EDIT Here is what I tried with an existing image with the Adobe RGB color space:

```
try { 
    $profile_path = "sRGB_IEC61966-2-1_black_scaled.icc";

    $image = new Imagick();
    $image->readImage("original-small.jpg");

    // TRY 1 > keeps the same Adobe RGB profile
    // $image->transformImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);

    // TRY 2 > strips all EXIF data + profile but does NOT assign new profile
    // $image->stripImage();
    // $image->transformImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);

    // TRY 3 > keeps the same Adobe RGB profile
    // $profile = file_get_contents($profile_path);
    // $image->profileImage("icc", $profile);
    // $image->transformImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);

    // TRY 4 > strips all EXIF data + profile but does NOT assign new profile
    // $image->stripImage();
    // $profile = file_get_contents($profile_path);
    // $image->profileImage("icc", $profile);
    // $image->transformImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);

} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception caught: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
echo $image->getImageBlob();
```

Answer (score 0):

I misread what you were asking. The code below changes an image from having being an Adobe style color profile to being a 'normal' web one.

```
$image = new Imagick("fullSize_MK3L7748.jpg");

// This isn't required - but it could be used
// $image->transformImageColorspace(\Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);

$profile = file_get_contents("sRGB_IEC61966-2-1_black_scaled.icc");
$image->profileImage("icc", $profile);
$image->writeImage("test_blackScaled.jpg");
```

Checking the images with identify now gives:

```
# identify -verbose fullSize_MK3L7748.jpg | grep icc
    icc:name: Adobe RGB (1998)
    Profile-icc: 560 bytes
```

and

```
# identify -verbose test_blackScaled.jpg | grep icc
    icc:name: IEC 61966-2-1 Default RGB Colour Space - sRGB
    Profile-icc: 3048 bytes
```

And the images should look almost the same - exact results may vary per browser.

Source image in aRGB
[image: Source aRGB image]

Output image
[image: Output image]

Comment: No, I tried this already with an existing image with Adobe RGB color space, no effect, it keeps the same profile. `$image = new Imagick(); $image->readImage("original-small.jpg"); $image->transformimagecolorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);`

Comment: Geeee, I don't believe it! Adding the trailing slash in front did the trick! `$image->transformImageColorspace(\Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);`  I almost gave this up.. thanks so much!! Any idea why I needed the slash?

Comment: NO, Hold on.. nope I tried with an image with sRGB. With an Adobe RGB image no conversion. I guess I give up on this.. :-| Also no help at all from my host.

Comment: Can you try with the top image I posted - it is an Adobe RGB image, and obviously the result should be the same as I get.

Comment: Hi Danack, thanks for the help. I can not try with your image because the profile is not present anymore, maybe because of StackOverflow? I have put a page online here: http://goo.gl/zcjktQ It seems I am confused about ***color space*** vs *profile* vs *color model* Apparently the Adobe RGB profiled images are still sRGB color space??